# Apache Beam : Transform an objects having a list of objects to multiple TableRows to write to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am working on a beam pipeline to process a json and write it to bigquery. The JSON is like this.

```
{
"message": [{
    "name": "abc",
    "itemId": "2123",
    "itemName": "test"

}, {
    "name": "vfg",
    "itemId": "56457",
    "itemName": "Chicken"
}],
"publishDate": "2017-10-26T04:54:16.207Z"
```

}

I parse this using Jackson to the below structure.

```
class Feed{
List<Message> messages; 
TimeStamp  publishDate;

}
```

---

```
public class Message implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String key;
private String value;

private Map<String, String> eventItemMap = new HashMap<>();
this property translate the list of map as a single map with all the key-value pair together. because,  the messages property will be parsed as list of HashMap objets for each key/value. This will be translated to a single map.
```

Now in my pipeline, I will convert the collection as

```
PCollection<KV<String, Feed>>
```

to write it to different tables based on a property in the class. I have written a transform to do this. 
The requirement is to create multiple TableRows based on the number of message objects. I have a few more properties in the JSON to along with publishDate which would be added to the tableRow and each message properties. 
So the table would be as follows.

```
id, name, field1, field2, message1.property1, message1.property2...

id, name, field1, field2, message2.property1, message2.property2...
```

I tried to create the below transformation. But, not sure how it will output multiple rows based on the message list.

```
private class BuildRowListFn extends DoFn<KV<String, Feed>, List<TableRow>> {

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
        Feed feed = context.element().getValue();

        List<Message> messages = feed.getMessage();
        List<TableRow> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.forEach((message) -> {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.set("column1", feed.getPublishDate());
            row.set("column2", message.getEventItemMap().get("key1"));
            row.set("column3", message.getEventItemMap().get("key2"));
            rows.add(row);
        }

        );

    }
```

But, this also will be a List which I won't be able to apply the BigQueryIO.write transformation.

---

### Updated as per the comment from "Eugene" aka @jkff

Thanks @jkff. Now, i have changed the code as you mentioned in the second paragraph.     context.output(row) inside messages.forEach, after setting table row  as

```
List<Message> messages = feed.getMessage();
        messages.forEach((message) -> {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.set("column2", message.getEventItemMap().get("key1"));
            context.output(row);
            }
```

Now, when i try to write this collection to BigQuery, as

```
rows.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(getTable(projectId, datasetId, tableName)).withSchema(getSchema())
                    .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                    .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
```

I am getting the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:331)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:301)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:200)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:63)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:283)
at com.chefd.gcloud.analytics.pipeline.MyPipeline.main(MyPipeline.java:284)


Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:759)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:809)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(StreamingWriteFn.java:126)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(StreamingWriteFn.java:96)
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are assuming that a `DoFn` can output only a single value per element. This is not the case: it can output any number of values per element - no values, one value, many values, etc. A `DoFn` can even [output values to multiple PCollection's](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs).

In your case, you simply need to call `c.output(row)` for every row in your `@ProcessElement` method, for example: `rows.forEach(c::output)`. Of course you'll also need to change the type of your `DoFn` to `DoFn<KV<String, Feed>, TableRow>`, because the type of elements in its output `PCollection` is `TableRow`, not `List<TableRow>` - you're just producing multiple elements into the collection for every input element, but that doesn't change the type.

An alternative method would be to do what you currently did, also do `c.output(rows)` and then apply `Flatten.iterables()` to flatten the `PCollection<List<TableRow>>` into a `PCollection<TableRow>` (you might need to replace `List` with `Iterable` to get it to work). But the other method is easier.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I just added .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.alwaysRetry()) and it was showing the issue. The data type which i was dynamically setting was of timeStamp for one key and the value was a string. Now this is inserting perfectly. Thanks a ton for the help. It really saved me!. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I was assuming the same. I think this is similar to Flink's flatMap. Cheers